# Awaiting function inside ApolloLink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo

I have this part of my code that runs every time I perform an apollo API call. My goal is to check if the user is authenticated and has the latest refreshed token before making the API call. My issue is that I am unable to await the commented out line because the function is not async

```
const authenticationLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {

  // const currentSession = await Auth.currentSession();
  // setAccessToken(currentSession.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken)

  if (typeof token === "string") {
    operation.setContext(() => ({
      headers: {
        Authorization: token
      }
    }));
  }

  return forward(operation);
});


const standardLink = ApolloLink.from([
  authenticationLink,
  httpLink
]);
```

If I make authenticationLink async do I need to alter the other code below to await it or can it stay the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

await is used with async. ([More details here)](https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-async-await-in-javascript-1d81bb079b2c)

Replace

```
const authenticationLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
```

To

```
const authenticationLink = new ApolloLink(async (operation, forward) => {
```

Comment: unfortunately that is causing errors in the code. Network error: inner.subscribe is not a function

Comment: Have a look at those Github answer then > https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2441